# .Net Core + DI: Class To Centralize Interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am new on .Net Core and Microsoft Dependency Injection and what I am trying to do is something similar to '.ToFactory()' (from ninject) which I can create a class containing all my interfaces services, avoiding a lot of IMyClassService on my controllers.
In .Net Framework + Ninject I used to do:

**NinjectModule**

```
Bind< IAppServiceFactory >().ToFactory();
```

**IAppServiceFactory class**

```
public interface IAppServiceFactory
{
    IAccessAgreementAppService AccessAgreement { get; }
    IAccessAgreementUserAppService AccessAgreementUser { get; }
    ...
```

**Controllers**

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
private readonly IAppServiceFactory _appServiceFactory;

public MyController(IMapper mapper,
    IAppServiceFactory appServiceFactory)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
    _appServiceFactory = appServiceFactory;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var all = _appServiceFactory.AccessAgreementUser.GetAll();
}
```

The main reason is having a cleaner controller, instead of

```
private readonly IAccessAgreementAppService _accessAgreementAppService;
private readonly IAccessAgreementUserAppService _accessAgreementUserAppService;
...
public MyController(IAccessAgreementAppService accessAgreementAppService,
    IAccessAgreementUserAppService accessAgreementUserAppService,
    ...
```

Comment: kinda defeats the purpose of DI. What if one service should be Scoped, while another should be Singleton or Transient. You are forcing them all to be whatever `IAppServiceFactory` ultimately ends up being.

Comment: Yees and I agree with it, but at the same time I think its also bad to have a bunch of services on my controllers, because some times I have a lot of entities/interfaces that I have to interact in only one method/action and to put all the business logic on controller it sounds so bad practice to me "/

Comment: Then you segregated your service too much if you are worried about injecting too many services. For example, you could combine those to in your example to be part of a `IAccessAgreementService`.

Comment: I think I don't understand, for example: every time I insert a AccessAgreement I should do something with AccessAgreementUser, but each one is separated in two diff classes, so to not have 2 injections on my controllers, how could I put these two in IAccessAgreementService and let controller safe from business logic?

Comment: To me, what you're doing feels like code smell to me. Seems to me that your `MyController` uses too many dependencies, and restructuring the code might solve that problem. But your example gives to little details to hint on doing that, and this is of course not what your question is about. There is no `ToFactory` equivalant in MS.DI. If you want to keep that interface, you will have to implement that `IAppServiceFactory` by hand and register it in the `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: What you call "cleaner" I would call "obscuring the dependencies", which is explicitly what dependency injection is supposed to avoid. If a class is overburdened with dependencies, that's probably a sign that it needs to be split up, not that the dependencies should be packaged in a bundle to hide this. Note that, just because you want to make methods available in a single controller, it does not mean that controller must be a do-anything class -- it can delegate to other controllers/classes and have those injected instead (and that's assuming better path mapping isn't the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request `IServiceProvider` and get the service yourself.

```
 public MyController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
         using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
         {
             var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAccessAgreementAppService();
             var all = service.GetAll();    
         }
 }
```

Comment: This the ultimate form of "ensuring the dependencies are no longer visible" and basically throws the concept of DI out the window. To now know what `MyController` depends on, you have to crack open the constructor, just like you would have to if no DI was being used at all. You also tie your code to a specific DI framework (although most folks only ever use one and wouldn't consider that a huge problem). It can be excused if it's "done just this once" but the temptation to just do this everywhere and pass the root service provider around so you can be "flexible" looms large.